# How to diagnose unclosed (incomplete) \iftrue or \ifnum?

Tags: errors

I'm working on a large LaTeX document (over 1000 pages).  I'm using `\include` liberally, and there are 47 `.tex` files in play.  At the end of the run I get these diagnostics:

```
(\end occurred when \iftrue on line 366 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 366 was incomplete)
```

The version of TeX I'm using announces itself as follows:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex 2015.5.11)  29 DEC 2015 17:28
```

My question: **how do I find the offending command?**  I've used Awk to print line 366 of each `.tex` file in the directory, but none of these files seem to have any kind of conditionals there.  I've also looked in the `.aux` files.  Local `.sty` files are not in play because none of them is 366 lines.

Where should I be looking?  What should I be looking for?  Is there a way to persuade TeX to disgorge the name of the offending file and not just the line number?  Perhaps some luatex trickery?

(I don't know how to provide a minimal example.  If I did, I probably could solve the problem.)

Comment: Even if the error tells you that the problem occurred in a certain line, it doesn't mean it necessarily occurred at that line. For example: if you define a `\newcommand` in your preamble (and it has a mistake), and then you use that same command in line 300, then your error will appear on line 300, but it's actually originating in your `\newcommand` definition in the preamble.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at

```
\tracingifs=2

\ifnum9=9

\stop
```

with `\tracingifs` set then the log shows more information:

```
(./file.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/01/01>
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
{vertical mode: \ifnum: (level 1) entered on line 4}
{\ifvmode: (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\ifnum: (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifvmode (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\iftrue: (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\ifx: (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifx (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \iftrue (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\iffalse: (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \iffalse (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\iffalse: (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \iffalse (level 2) entered on line 6}
{internal vertical mode: \ifnum: (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\ifnum: (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\ifvoid: (level 4) entered on line 6}
{\ifvbox: (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifvbox (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\ifx: (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifx (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifx (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\ifx: (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifx (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifx (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\iffalse: (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \iffalse (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\iffalse: (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \iffalse (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\ifx: (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifx (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifx (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifvoid (level 4) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifvoid (level 4) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifnum (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifnum (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\ifnum: (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\ifdim: (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifdim (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifdim (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifnum (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\ifnum: (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\ifnum: (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifnum (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\ifnum: (level 4) entered on line 6}
{\ifnum: (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 5) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifnum (level 4) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 4) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 3) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifnum (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\ifnum: (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\else: \ifnum (level 2) entered on line 6}
{\fi: \ifnum (level 2) entered on line 6}
 )
(\end occurred when \ifnum on line 4 was incomplete)
```

So you can see it is in this case an unmatched `(level 1)`  `\ifnum`

Working upwards in the log from the line

```
    {vertical mode: \ifnum: (level 1) entered on line 4}
```

you see the first `(` shows `(./file.tex` so it is line 4 of `file.tex` that has the offending if.

Answer (score 2):

Try to search the eventual \end{docuement} in the one of files input before main file ...

Answer (score 1):

Some tips for large log file:

- Since it's really hard to look for `(file` and `)` in that case, you can use some LaTeX hook to log some message when the file changes:

  ```
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \seq_new:N \__file_list
  \seq_put_right:Nn \__file_list {\msg_expandable_error:nn{}{this~cannot~happen!}}
  \seq_put_right:Nn \__file_list {<main~file>}
  \AddToHook{file/before}{
      \seq_put_right:NV \__file_list \CurrentFile
      \wlog {enter~file\use_none:n{}::\CurrentFile}
  }
  \AddToHook{file/after}{
      \seq_pop_right:NN \__file_list \__last_file
      \seq_get_right:NN \__file_list \__last_file
      \wlog {return~to~file\use_none:n{}::\__last_file}
  }
  \ExplSyntaxOff
  ```

  (obviously the effect is, you get a line `enter file::X` and `return to file::X` in the log. Search for `file::`. The `\use_none:n {}` is to prevent the message from being found while doing macro expansion, if macro logging is enabled.)
- A "binary search" alternative is to insert a (commented) empty line to some TeX files, then see if the line number increases. (it's "brute force", but works most of the time, except if catcode is weird.)
- Note that, even if some particular `\if` is reported as the culprit, it's not necessarily the cause. For example

  ```
  \if ... % A

      \if ... % B (accidentally inserted)

  \fi % C
  ```

  Clearly the one at `B` is at fault here, nevertheless TeX will report `A` is incomplete. And `A` might be deep buried inside some library code (e.g. if you have incomplete `\if` within some `.sty` file this can happen)
- Generally speaking, it's useful to search for `if.* <line number>}` (regex) from the end of the file, since you can observe that
  if there are multiple such `\if`, the last one will be likely at fault;
  nevertheless if the first hit is a `\fi` then skip through one `\if`.

  Example log

  ```
  {\if entered on line X}
  {\else: \if entered on line X}
  {\fi: \if entered on line X}

  {\if entered on line X}
  {\else: \if entered on line X}
  {\fi: \if entered on line X}

  {\if entered on line X}
  {\else: \if entered on line X}
  {\fi: \if entered on line X}

  {\if entered on line X}

  {\if entered on line X}
  {\else: \if entered on line X}
  {\fi: \if entered on line X}
  ```

  In this example it can be seen that if you search for the log lines from the end backwards, you'll first see a `\fi`, then skip one `\if`, then find the offending command immediately. (there's `(level X)` to partially help with search for matching lines, but no more than that.)